# EF SQL Connection string not conforming to specification

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

Ok, enough pulling my hair out. This all worked on previous projects.

I'm beginning to think there is a problem somewhere else in the project. That said, I did at one point, have a wrong username and it complained immediately. That means I think it is connection to the SQL Server just error parsing on the Entity Framework Side of things.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Connection String**

```
<add name="QuizDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.QuizModel.csdl|res://*/Model.QuizModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.QuizModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myserver.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=mydatabasename;Integrated Security=False;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFrameworkEncrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**Error**

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ToString()\r\n   at System.String.Concat(Object[] args)\r\n   at AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException.get_Message()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.HttpError..ctor(Exception exception, Boolean includeErrorDetail)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass8.<CreateErrorResponse>b__7(Boolean includeErrorDetail)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateErrorResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, Func`2 errorCreator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.DefaultExceptionHandler.Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.DefaultExceptionHandler.HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.<HandleAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 111.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
        "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)"
    }
}
```

Comment: `EntityFrameworkEncrypt` - add a ";"

Comment: Well spotted, but that was actually a typo here only. The real reason was that there was an apostrophe in my password. Epic Fail of an evening for me!